# Select dropdown list obscured when inside Modal (Materializecss)

Tags: css, select, modal-dialog, dropdown, materialize

This is a question specific to the [Materializecss](https://materializecss.com/) framework, and two components within it, namely [Modal](https://materializecss.com/modals.html) and [Select](https://materializecss.com/select.html). When a Select input inside a modal has a long options list (9+), the options list flows ouutside the modal container, cutting off the top of the list, so that the user can't actually see all the options. What is the best way to handle a long options list when it is inside a container that has a fixed/max height?
[image]

Comment: You specifically need to show the CSS/HTML code that displays this modal, otherwise we can only guess what is going on here. Please go the extra mile. However, if you are using FLEXBOX CSS with 'justify-content: center' (or any other FBL attribute 'center'ing) to position content combined with 'overflow: hidden' it is possible that content moves out of sight... Noticed this myself on occasion. Can't remember specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a max-height and you can manage overflow by scroll. I assume that your dropdown menu class is dropdown-menu in my answer and you can adapt it to yours.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```